# Parse a single Line of XML into a HashMap

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm building an android app that communicates to a web server and am struggling with the following scenario:

Given ONE line of XML in a String eg:

```
"<test one="1" two="2" />"
```

I would like to extract the values into a HashMap so that:

```
map.get("one") = "1"
map.get("two") = "2"
```

I already can do this with a full XML document using the SAX Parser, this complains when i try to just give it the above string with a MalformedUrlException: Protocol not found

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder;
Document doc = null;
builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
doc = builder.parse("<test one="1" two="2" />"); //here
```

I realize some regex could do this but Id really rather do it properly.

The same behaviour can be found at [http://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#XMLin](http://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aSimple#XMLin) which is what the web server uses.

Can anyone help? Thanks :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DocumentBuilder.parse(String)` treats the string as a URL. Try this instead:

```
Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(text)));
```

(where `text` contains the XML, of course).

Comment: Fantastic, It didn't occur to me that it was seeing it as a URL despite the message...long day. Anyway thanks a bunch :D